# SIGSEGV fault in qml application on app.exec()

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qml, msys2

I'm trying to set up the environment on the new machine for our application written on Qt15.2 with GCC compiler version 10.2, and because it is a windows application, I get the qt and gcc from the MSYS2.

The compiling process is going well, but when I'm trying to launch the application, it crashes with the message: "the program has unexpectedly finished. the process was ended forcefully"
The same I obtained if trying to compile a blank qml app with a single ApplicationWindow in it.

I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Run it in the debugger and update your question with a stack trace of the crash.

Comment: I had this issue, in one of my projects but it doesn't relate to msys2 or compiler because I test MinGW in windows,GCC, and g++ in Linux, but my program again crashed in the line app.exe()   in the main function when I use debug . when I use run that didn't happen. I can't find why this happened.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, there is no message in debugging. However, I have found the solution already - it was a Windows bug. Updating the system has helped.

Comment: @SweetOrange really???? why? means which part of OS does Qt use that makes crash in app.exe() line.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was found - I used "dependencies" (https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to find out, which .dll libraries are missing. The problem was in some Windows libraries because it was a fresh system downloaded from Microsoft site without any updating made yet and seems to be very old. I had updated the system and everything is working fine now.